# Neo4j: get index property 'name' in cypher query as a return value

Tags: neo4j, cypher, py2neo

Hi I'm new to neo4j and cypher. I've built my database such that there are multiple depths in the graph you can start at. In my example the graph is a tree the root node is an index and nodes at level 4 are indices.  I'm using py2neo to develop the graph and I use the get_or_create_indexed_node method in accordance with: [py2neo documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/py2neo/neo4j.html)

```
patient_node = graph_db.get_or_create_indexed_node('patients', 'name',
patients[patient_id])
```

but when I run my cypher query such that I land on a index node I can only get the id. For example when I do this:

```
start n=node:rootnode(name='root'), p=node:patients('name:*')
match n-[:chrm]-()-[:pos]-()-[:patient]-p-[:variant]->vars 
where (has(vars.mutations))  return p.name"
```

I get error saying:
The property 'name' does not exist on Node[84361]

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned that you are adding any properties to the nodes returned from `get_or_create_indexed_node`. The function is `get_or_create_indexed_node(index, key, value, properties=None)`, so the values you provided are only the index name, key and value.

You need to create the node like this:

```
node = graph_db.get_or_create_indexed_node('patients', 
                                           'name', patients[patient_id], 
                                           patient_properties)
```